# Creating a var from data created by another class

Tags: php

I am having problems creating a variable with data from another class. Here is what I am doing...

```
 <?PHP
  class Customers extends Controller {

      private $foo = $this->session->userdata('foo');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something more like this:

```
class Customers extends Controller 
{
  private $foo;
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->foo = $this->session->userdata('foo');
  }
}
```

It's hard to know for sure without knowing more about your project.

Comment: Correct in principle, but `$this->session` can't be an initialized object at that point yet....

Comment: @Pekka, That's why I'm calling the parent's constructor, as that's the only way it could possibly exist at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it with constructor because you are inhering from parent class:

```
class Customers extends Controller {
  private $foo = null;

  function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->foo = $this->session->userdata('foo');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible: `$this` doesn't exist at the moment when you define the class, and you can't call functions at all at this point at all.

You will need to assign `$foo` in the constructor, after `$this->session` has been initialized. (@konforce beat me to the example.)